# String input doesn't work in if-else statement

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java, and I created some sort of a mini game, and I wanted players to choose whether or not they want to play again, I tried changing my start boolean variable into static type and adding some lines of code, but the code doesn't seem to work, every time I play the game, it did ask me if I want to replay or not, but the problem is that even though I typed "yes" to the console at the end, the game doesn't seem to restart. Can anyone help me please, I would be really appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Rocks, papers, scissors game complied by William To.
public class RockPaperScissor {
static int gamePlays = 0;
static boolean start = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (start){
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random comOutput = new Random();
        System.out.println("Do you choose rock, paper or scissor?");
        String userChoice = userInput.nextLine();
        int comChoice = comOutput.nextInt(2);
        switch (userChoice){

        case "rock":
            if(comChoice == 0){
                System.out.println("I choose rock too! That's a draw!");
            } else if(comChoice == 1){
                System.out.println("I choose paper! I win!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I choose scissor! You win!");
            }
            break;

        case "paper":
            if(comChoice == 0){
                System.out.println("I choose rock! You win!");
            } else if(comChoice == 1){
                System.out.println("I choose paper too! That's a draw!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I choose scissor! I win!");
            }
            break;

        case "scissor":
            if(comChoice == 0){
                System.out.println("I choose rock! I win!");
            } else if(comChoice == 1){
                System.out.println("I choose paper! You win!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I choose scissor too! That's a draw!");
            }
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("I don't think that's an option.");
            break;
        }
        gamePlays++;
        System.out.println("You've played " + gamePlays + " games.");

               //BELOW IS THE PART I want to ask, what's wrong? 

        System.out.println("Do you want to play again?"); 
        String playAgain = userInput.next();
        if (playAgain == "yes"){
            System.out.println("Restarting game...");
            start = true;
        } else if (playAgain == "no") {
            System.out.println("Quitting game.");
            start = false;
        }
    }
}   
}
```

The print out from Eclipse:

```
Do you choose rock, paper or scissor?  
rock **//my input**    
I choose paper! I win!  
You've played 1 games.  
Do you want to play again?    
yes **//my input**    
Do you choose rock, paper or scissor?  
paper **//my input**    
I choose paper too! That's a draw!  
You've played 2 games.  
Do you want to play again?  
no **//my input**  
Do you choose rock, paper or scissor?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO not `==` again :_(

Comment: 100 th time i'm seeing this question.

Comment: @Baadshah That's the amount I saw this question in the first 3 days on SO.

Comment: sorry guys, I just didn't know what to do since I did not study on that yet, I'm studying Java on my own at home so it's kinda hard for me to find all the right solution for my code, anyway, thanks guys! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparison between strings needs the [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of `==`. So this:

```
if (playAgain == "yes"){
    System.out.println("Restarting game...");
    start = true;
} else if (playAgain == "no") {
    System.out.println("Quitting game.");
    start = false;
}
```

Has to become this:

```
if (playAgain.equals("yes")){
    System.out.println("Restarting game...");
    start = true;
} else if (playAgain.equals("no")) {
    System.out.println("Quitting game.");
    start = false;
}
```

In order to work properly.

However, I suggest to use [String#equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29), because with `equals`, the comparison is case-sensitive, so if user inputs i.e. `Yes` or `yEs`, `playAgain.equals("yes")` will return `false`

**UPDATE**

As Maroun Maroun says, it is better to use

```
"yes".equals(playAgain)
```

and

```
"no".equals(playAgain)
```

Because if playAgain is `null` it won't throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: +1. Although I prefer to `"yes".equals(playAgain)` just in case `playAgain` is `null`, it won't be NPE.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I always wondered why people always put the string literal first. Now I know, thanks!

Comment: ohhh, so that was the problem... Thanks everyone for helping me out :D , I'm kinda like a newbie so... :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
    if ("yes".equals(playAgain)) {
        System.out.println("Restarting game...");
        start = true;
    } else if ("no".equals(playAgain)) {
        System.out.println("Quitting game.");
        start = false;
    }
```

[String#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) checks the character equality of string, `==` checks memory reference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably this line

```
if (playAgain == "yes")
```

(and the one later for no).

Strings in Java are objects. This means that two strings might have the same *content*, i.e. contain the same text, but still not be "the same" as far as `==` is concerned. To compare two strings and see if they contain the same text, use this:

```
if (playAgain.equals("yes"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the way in which `String` comparision is done.

`playAgain == "yes"`, This check will check for object equality.

However in this case, value of object needs to be compared, following code will work for you.

```
playAgain.equals("yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need compare string using `String.equals()` method and not `==`

The `equals` method compares for the value of the string and `==` checks whether both the objects refer to the same same object or not.

Comment: _Also, you need to put break statement after each case in switch block else it won't break out of the switch block and will execute all the following switch cases_ In the code the OP posted, he **is** doing that.

Comment: Instead, you can just upvote the answer and accept it so that it will also help others readers to know it is helpful :)

Comment: I can't, it requires 15 population.